# C++ NEW Object as parameter (Like Java)

Tags: java, c++, class, object, coding-style

I'm coding some stuff in C++, and as always we have some "thoughts" if something similar exists on the language...

I'm now, with an doubt about objects passing as parameters.

What I always do, is create a new object, and pass it's instance as a pointer, like this:

```
mObject* obj1 = new mObject();
obj1->callback(the_callback_function);

function_that_needs_obj(obj1); // (or the reference, if I didn't instantiated a pointer).
```

That's OK, works OK, there is no problem with this. But, as I used Java, I used to do like this:

```
function_that_needs_obj(new mObject(){
    public void onCallback(){
        // Custom code enters here....
    }
});
```

Is there any "sort" of use in C++ like this? Because for EACH callback that I need to create: One `Extended class`, or, one `functionNamedVeryLongBecauseThereAreMany` must be written on TOP of the code, and that kind of "confuses" a lot the code...

And also, all Object variable, are not accessible trough `this` if I assing an FUNCTION callback...

Comment: Callbacks in C++ are even easier. Just take any callable type and pass a lambda.

Comment: @chris , there is no problem in "implementing" callbacks, It's just a matter of enchancing code... If I send a callable type to the new object, the callable type will not be able to `access` the object data, only if it uses the global scope.

Comment: Sorry... I'm not English native...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you compiler support c++11， you can use lambda expression like this:

```
function_that_needs_obj([]()
                        {
                           // Custom code enters here....
                        });
```

[What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

Comment: Sorry, I never heard of that compiler

Comment: "Arduino" is not in fact a Compiler, it uses GCC, but is there any ways to "enable" this?

Answer (score 0):

You could find what you need in boost lambda!